# Output Mismatch while convert string value to date object

Tags: java

I have tried to convert string value to date object. I have tried some logic, but it didn't work. see my code :

```
public class Test {     
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try{
            Test obj= new Test();
            String date="2015-03-30T11:54:46.162430057Z";
            Date dt=obj.getServerDate(date);
            //System.out.println(dt);
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
    public Date getServerDate(String str_date)
    {
        if (str_date == null)
            return null;
        SimpleDateFormat fmt = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'");
        System.out.println("Given date:" + str_date);

        Date pars_date = null;
        try 
        {
            pars_date = fmt.parse(str_date);
            System.out.println("Parsed date:" + pars_date);
        } 
        catch (Exception e) 
        {   
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return pars_date;    
    }    
}
```

The above code give the following output:

```
Given date:2015-03-30T11:54:46.162430057Z
Parsed date:Wed Apr 01 09:01:56 IST 2015
```

In the output the Given date and Parsed date is mismatch, I couldn't find any mistake in my code. Please let me know if you find the solution...

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have a look at the new way of handling dates and time in java.time package. Using these new classes is less error prone and it makes the intent of the code clearer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with matching the server format with your parsing format.

You specify .SSS to handle milliseconds, but in the default configuration the number of "S" does not matter, SimpleDateFormat will consume until the next delimiter. This means that it will parse the first fields, and in the end add 162430057 milliseconds (about 45 hours) which gets you to the (correct, but unwanted and unexpected) Wed Apr 01 09:01:56 IST 2015.

If you are using Java 8 I recommend instead looking at [DateTimeFormatter](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html) which can handle nanoseconds or if pre Java 8 use [Joda Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/).

If you are running on JDK 1.3 (which was End-Of-Life 2006/2007 depending on vendor) and you are certain of the time format, then you could use:

```
fmt(text.substring(0, 23) + 'Z')
```

or possibly remove the `+ 'Z'`and remove the `'Z'` from the format.

Using Date you will lose the nano second precision in any case as Date only holds milliseconds.

Comment: I have to execute this code in jdk1.3. So I can't use Joda Time for this code. Please tell me the solution for my convenience.